# Existence of projective and injective resolutions for specific modules

Tags: modules, homology-cohomology

I try to show that for each vector space there exist projective and injective resolutions such that only one term is different from zero. Similarly, for each abelian group there exist projective and injective resolutions such that at most two terms are different from zero. I know that for each module there exist projective and injective resolutions. I don't know how to include the conditions here in the proof.

Comment: For the projective resolution of an abelian group, think about how you would relate that group to a free abelian group. As for the resolutions of a vector space, do you know that all vector spaces are both projective and injective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** let $R$ be a ring. Show that

- given any $R$-module $M$, there is a free module $F$ and an epimorphism $p \colon F \to M$.
- if $R$ is either $\mathbb Z$ or a field, then submodules of free modules are free.

Thus

$$
0 \to \ker p \hookrightarrow F \xrightarrow{p} M \to 0
$$

is a *free* resolution  of $M$ of at most two terms. If $M$ was free to begin with (as is for a vector space) we can take $F = M$ and $p = id$. Hence $\ker p = 0$ and the resolution has only one term.